# Selecting Individual rows using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out if there's anyway to use GROUP_CONCAT to select rows based on these parameters.

[image]

What I'm trying to to get the lowest time for every single style/zonegroup.

AKA:

```
Lowest Time for Style 0 ZoneGroup 0
Lowest Time for Style 0 ZoneGroup 1
Lowest Time for Style 0 ZoneGroup 2
Lowest Time for Style 1 ZoneGroup 0
Lowest Time for Style 2 ZoneGroup 0
...
```

I could have multiple queries sent through my plugin, but I would like to know if this could be firstly eliminated with a GROUP_CONCAT function, and if so -how.

Here's what I could do, but I'ld like to know if this could be converted into one line.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STYLES; i++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < MAX_ZONEGROUPS; x++) {
        Transaction.AddQuery("SELECT * FROM `t_records` WHERE mapname = 'de_dust2' AND style = i AND zonegroup = x ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1;");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Include `counter-strike` in the tags? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `group_concat()`.  You want to filter records, so use `WHERE` . . . in this case with a correlated subquery:

```
select r.*
from t_records r
where r.mapname = 'de_dust2' and
      r.timestamp = (select min(r2.timestamp)
                     from t_records r2
                     where r2.mapname = r.mapname and
                           r2.style = r.style and 
                           r2.zonegroup = r.zonegroup
                    );
```

Comment: Quick question, what does r.timestamp / r2.timestamp reference to? I might be getting confused since I have a column named timestamp

Comment: @RedXephos2k11 . . . These are qualified column names and refer, respectively, to the `timestamp` column in the outer `from` clause and the one in the correlated subquery.

Comment: I think you were confused, I was trying to get the lowest time from the column "time" and not "timestamp", I've corrected it though, thanks